# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

**UPDATE:** The election has now [been scheduled](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/75). Thanks for all who expressed interest in nominating.

---

The last bioinfo mod elections happened 465 days ago and with the recent power vacuum created by my resignation, we all kind of feel it's the time to consider to have another mod elections. However, for the elections to have any point, we would need at least a handful of ambitious candidates, so here comes the million-dollar question.

Can you see yourself carrying the diamond badge? If you would be happy to self-nomitate yourself, please post an answer to this question!

The next steps will depend how many responses we will get, so don't be shy :-).

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for helping out with keeping the site up and running.

Self-nominating as a current moderator, for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to see you go again @KamilSJaron.

I'm definitely more than happy to be a candidate for an election.